# Creating a role, then giving the role to a member doesn't work, is there a better way to handle this? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to create a role based off a message, then once that role is created, I want to give it to those that are mentioned in the same message. The role gets created perfectly fine, but the correct role isn't give to the user.

I've tried going by the name, but that leads to the role not being found, so I'm trying to get the role based off the position that it is in, but when I need to give the role out, it doesn't seem to be in that correct position

```
var nameOC = getClanName(message.content);
        console.log(nameOC);
        message.guild.createRole({
            name: nameOC,
            hoist: true,
            mentionable: false,
            position: 1,
        });
        var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.position === 1);
        console.log(role);
        list.members.forEach(member => {
           if(message.content.includes(member)){
              member.addRoles(role);          
            }
        });
        message.channel.send(nameOC);
```

The role gets made perfectly fine with the correct name, however it gives the role that was previously the first one, not the one that was just made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Sync vs Async

Say you're planning on picking your friend up to go to a sporting event. You're not sure when they want you to come, so you call them on the phone and ask them. They think about it for a while, and then tell you a time. You got the information you requested, so you hang up. In programming terms, this would be an example of synchronous code (sometimes thought of as "normal" code in Node.js).

Put yourself back in the same situation. However, when you call your friend this time, they're very busy. You don't want to bother them so you ask them to call you later. You hang up, but now you wait. An hour later, they call you back and tell you the time. This is the thought process of asynchronous code.

There's a lot more that goes on behind the screen, but for simplicity's sake, I'm not going to bombard you with all that information.

---

#### Promises

> The `Promise` object represents the eventual completion (or failure) of an asynchronous operation, and its resulting value.

<sup>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise</sup>

The [`Guild.createRole()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=createRole) method returns a Promise.

> A `Promise` is in one of these states:
>
> - *pending*: initial state, neither fulfilled nor rejected.
> - *fulfilled*: meaning that the operation completed successfully.
> - *rejected*: meaning that the operation failed.

<sup>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise</sup>

Although you called the method to create the role, it isn't created instantaneously. The Promise is in its *pending* state.

---

#### Solutions

So, how do we retrieve the result of a Promise? We have to wait for it.

- Keeping a simple flow, you can use the [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) keyword. All it does is wait for the Promise to be fulfilled or rejected before continuing the execution of further code. Consider the following example:

  ```js
  // Asynchronous context (meaning within an async function) needed to use 'await.'

  var role = await message.guild.createRole(...);
  console.log(role);
  // Continue using the 'role' variable...
  ```
- Alternatively, you could use [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) chains. The callback will be called with the returned value upon the fulfillment of the Promise. In some contexts, this is simple. However, callbacks can get messy very quickly, and the scope of the returned values will be limited. Consider this example:

  ```js
  message.guild.createRole(...)
    .then(role => {
      console.log(role);
      // Continue using the 'role' variable...
    });
  ```

---

#### Error Handling

When a Promise is rejected, it means something went wrong. Errors originating from rejected Promises must be caught. If they aren't, you'll receive a warning in the console with the error.

- You can attach [`catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) methods which will work similarly to `then()`, except returning the error as its callback parameter and only being called upon rejection. Consider this condensed example:

  ```js
  message.guild.createRole(...)
    .then(role => {...})
    .catch(console.error);
  ```
- Instead of attaching multiple `catch()` methods, you can use a [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) statement. If any Promises inside of the `try` block are rejected, the code inside the `catch` block is executed. For instance:

  ```js
  try {
    var role = await message.guild.createRole(...);
    await role.delete(); // Maybe not a logical example...
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  ```

---

#### Resources

- [Discord.js Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome)
- [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Comment: I learned so much from that one comment, it all makes so much more sense, you're a legend.